# Python with Flask: How to keep the connection alive while the user is waiting (preventing a timeout error for user)?

Tags: python, flask, queue, connection, keep-alive

I have an online app running Python and Flask that provide files to users.

The files are built on demand, that is, when the user place the request, the app will build the file and deliver to the user. The building of the file usually takes a few seconds, that is fine, but there are some large files that may need over 2 minutes to be built, that generates a timeout error at the requesting user.

How can I keep the user's connection alive while the file is built, preventing the timeout error?

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the user to another page and then show the results when it's ready using JS. Probably not the best way to do this, but it's simple and easy to understand.

Process the response by creating a thread with an id to manage the task and then redirecting the user.

```py
from flask import request
from threading import Thread

tasks = {}

def process_task(id):
  tasks[id] = 0
  # do task here
  tasks[id] = task_result

@app.route('/check')
def check():
  return tasks[request.args.get('id')]

@app.route('/response')
def response():
  if request.args.get('code') is None:
    # assign random id to task
    task = str(random.randint(1, 9999))
    Thread(target=lambda: process_task(task)).start()
    return redirect(f'/response?code={task}', code=302)
  else:
    return render_template('response_page')
```

HTML

```html
<body>
Task is loading...
</body>
<script>
  setInterval(async function() {
    // refresh until task is completed
    const a = await fetch('/check?id='+'{{request.args.get("code")}}')
    const b = await a.json()
    if (b != 0) {
      // process task here
    }
  }, 1000)
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it is useful for many situations. For the particular problem I have, the user app is expecting an audio file; if anything else is provided, then an error is generated to the user. I think what may works is something similar to the `keep-alive` command used by many FTP clients to keep the connection open and avoiding to be closed because of no activity.